# Parse xml result to uitableview in swift

Tags: swift, xml-parsing

How can i parse xml result to tableview with two lines per cell in Swift?

I want to show the result like this in a table view

TableView

================

userID: brat_peet

password: 12124521

================

userID: Miketyson

password: Miketyson

================

How can i do it?

Here is my xml result.

```
<Record table="User" partial="true">    
<Field name="userID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[brat_peet]]></Field>
<Field name="password" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[12124521]]></Field>       
</Record>

<Record table="User" partial="true">    
<Field name="userID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[Miketyson]]></Field>
<Field name="password" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[Miketyson]]></Field>
</Record>

<Record table="User" partial="true">    
<Field name="userID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[Kennedy]]></Field> 
<Field name="password" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[754123654]]></Field>     
</Record>

</ATBResponse>
```

Comment: NSXMLParser? What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried it, my problem is how can i parse the data to a uitableview with two cell in swift. I'm new in swift. If you can help me, it'll very helpful ! thank's in advance !

Comment: First understand how to parse data, secondly understand how to play with UITableView. There should be a lot of tutorials for both of your issues. Your question is quite common.

Comment: i already read a lot of tutorials, until now i can't resolve it!. It's so important for me, if you can help me please do it

Comment: If you don't show what you've tried, we can't guess what's wrong. We can help you to determine where are your errors, but repeating what say already a tutorial adapted to your particular example is not helpful for StackOverFlow.

Comment: you can use the same xml result above for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

**For the tableView:**

"Two lines per cell" is an irrelevant value. You can use "custom" style cells and put in as many Text Labels (and images and whatever) you want inside each cell. So, to have two "lines" per cell you can simply choose "custom" cell, drag it down to increase the size and insert two Labels inside.

**For the XML parsing:**

First you have to understand how a XML is parsed in Swift. Here's a tutorial I wrote:
https://medium.com/@lucascerro/understanding-nsxmlparser-in-swift-xcode-6-3-1-7c96ff6c65bc

In your case, you have to construct your code so you only check the `<Field>` element when inside a `<Record>` element. Then you differentiate between `"username"` and `"password"` data by checking your `<Field>`'s `attributes`.

**For the String:**

Lastly, your resulting `foundCharacters` will not be the final data you need. There are many methods of the `String` type that can solve this. One example is to use the method `removeRange` to remove the starting and ending characters, since they appear to always be the same ones (in your case: `"<![CDATA["` and `"]]>"`, assuming you're getting them returned as `String` types).